# Replace Brackets on Array

Tags: java

I have an array like this: `["one", two"]`

If I make `array.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim();`, 
I will have: `"one, two"`

What I really want is `"one", "two"`

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

This is a simple program to explain my question:

```
 ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    array.add("one");
    array.add("two");

    String stringArray = array.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(stringArray);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: what is that you want to do?

Comment: `array[0]` and `array[1]`?

Comment: And note that this is confusing: `["one", two"]`

Comment: You finished the program or asking for solution. your question is confusing

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe what are you trying to achieve and what is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: Pshemo No. It´s not. It´s a perfect clear question if you run my edited code

Comment: I run it, and I still don't know why would you expect to get `"one", "two"` over `"one, two"` or more importantly, why you *want* to get `"one", "two"`. Also what is the real difference between results? What they stand for?

Comment: You are not answering the question. I have a specification that need "one", "two" over "one, two". If I needed "OnE", "Two" it´s not really the matter here.

Comment: Because I have old technology and I´m converting to Java. The results must continue exactly the same.

Comment: There are many possible solutions which I could think of, but they are not good for all cases. For instance I don't know if you need to use Gson. If not then simple `array.stream().map(s->"\""+s+"\"").collect(Collectors.joining(", "));` would be enough.

Comment: I also don't know if result must be `"one",  "two"` (with space after comma) or is `"one","two"` also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
array.stream().map(s->"\""+s+"\"").collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

which will first surround each strings with quotes, then join them using `,`

For Java 7

```
String delimiter = ", ";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (!array.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append('"').append(array.get(0)).append('"');
}
for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(delimiter).append('"').append(array.get(i)).append('"');
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I´m using jdk 1.7 and not 1.8

Comment: Do you have to use 1.7? Java 8 is standard version today.

Comment: Perfect. It´s exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just replace comma's with some extra `"`'s

```
array.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim().replace(", ", "\", \"")
```

(Not tested, but you get the idea)